# how can i use firefox require function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, firefox-addon, webpack, es6-module-loader

I'm writing firefox add-on in typescript (and i use webpack for building project), and i'm confused by this question.
There is `require` function in firefox, i use it like:

`let { Cu, Cc, Ci } = require('chrome');`

But typescript(more precisely tslint) looks at it as import/export statement and requires change expression.
I've declared require:

`declare function require(moduleId:string) : any;`

but it does not give any result.
Also i've changed `no-var-requires` option in tslint.json, but it did not pay any attention.

So the question is - is it possible to use firefox `require` function in typescript code and how to drag this function through the typescript, tslint and webpack (it also has his sights set on `require`)?

Hint - this is about background script, not a content or popup.

Comment: Very very cool. I love typescript, but have not used it in Firefox projects yet.

Comment: ok, guys, there are two ways i was found:

Comment: ffrequire=eval('require'); further use ffrequire in code. Or edit webpack config like: externals: [{"sdk/self"         : "require('sdk/self')"}] and use normal require in code.

Comment: Superb! Thank you for sharing!

Comment: You are welcome! Notice - first way is not the best if you want to distribute via firefox store - it needs 'unsafe-eval' content_security_policy in manifest which is unacceptable for reviewers.

Answer (score 1):

> Also i've changed no-var-requires option in tslint.json, but it did not pay any attention.

Delete that rule completely. If that doesn't work restart your dev environment.